# C++ print an array like you do in ruby

Tags: c++, arrays, ruby

Are there any way to print an array like you do in ruby within the C++ ordinary library or do I have to do something with extensions? I understand there is a way where you do for example a for loop but are there any ways like where you in ruby just type

```
print array
```

I would like to do the same in c++ where you type something like

```
std::cout << array;
```

Comment: Write a function called `printArray()` then call it each time you want to print an array.

Comment: You probably need to create a loop

Comment: There is no built in facility in C++ or the C++ library to do what you are asking out of the box. You will need to either write your own function to do it or search for a library that produces the output you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in C++. I recommend using

```
for(auto a : yourArray){
    std::cout << a;
}
```

If you need to use this often you could write a function or template for it.

Comment: It's probably better to use `for(const auto& a : yourArray)`. If it's an array of primitive type the compiler should optimise out the reference and it avoids making copied for fat types.

Comment: This solution also assumes there's a stream `<<` operator defined for the type contained in the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such an easy way in C++ but you may use the

```
for(auto string : yourArray){
    std::cout << string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what Array is. Is it an stl container or something you put together?

In either case you can write a new operator << to handle it:

```
std::ostream operator <<(std::ostrean s,const MyArray& mine)
{
   for (const a& : mine)
     s << a;
   return s;
}
```

which probably seems like syntactic gloss, but for the standard containers you write it once and use it for any vector:

```
template <typename T> std::ostream operator <<(std::ostream s, const std::vector<T>& mine)
{
   for (const a& : mine)
     s << a;
   return s;
}
```

Then write it again for set and map, and etc. I'm sure you could do one definition that works for any container that has iterators using some of the c++14 cleverness, but this is a starting point.